# How to "iterate" through a SQL result in stored procedure but avoid using a cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am fairly new to doing more involved SQL work.

My goal is to email using the results of a query to drive email creation. I intend to create a stored procedure and schedule this twice a week (there will be at most 20 emails, this will not be heavy email load) on SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT ProjectCodes.ProjectCode, COUNT(Projects.ProjectsID),  ProjectApprovers.EmailApprover
FROM Projects 
INNER JOIN ProjectCodes
    ON Projects.ProjectCodesID=ProjectCodes.ProjectCodesID
INNER JOIN ProjectApprovers
    ON Projects.ProjectCodesID=ProjectApprovers.ProjectCodesID
WHERE ProjectApprovers.IsPrimaryApprover=1
group by ProjectCodes.ProjectCode, ProjectApprovers.EmailApprover
```

This returns something similar to:

```
+-------------+-------+--------------+
| ProjectCode | Count | EmailAddress |
+-------------+-------+--------------+
| Code1       |     4 | Email1       |
| Code2       |     2 | Email2       |
| Code3       |     2 | Email3       |
| Code4       |     3 | Email4       |
+-------------+-------+--------------+
```

What I would like to do is basically loop through this result, running the following:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients= 'email1',     --email address from above query
@subject='Test email',
@body='You have X projects waiting'    -- where X is the COUNT() term
```

for each of the rows.

My understanding is I could do this somewhat straightforward for each entry if I use a cursor, but, all the documentation and Stack Overflow results I've found strongly suggest this is not a good strategy.

What is the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 7):

Usually the reason cursors are discouraged is because *there's ways to do what you want without using a cursor*.  Many developers start in procedural languages so loops are common and natural.  Thinking in terms of set-based operations is not "natural" and so cursors are used to mimic loops.

In this case, using a cursor is appropriate because there's no set-based way to send individual emails.

Whether or not it's a good idea to send emails directly from you database server is another question...

Comment: This is one of the times when using a cursor is completely appropriate.  Dump the query output into a temp table and iterate over that.

Comment: What do you mean by a "set-based operation"?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is going into some temp table or table var, you can add a row number to that result set, like so:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProjectCodes.ProjectCode) RowNumber, ProjectCodes.ProjectCode, COUNT(Projects.ProjectsID),  ProjectApprovers.EmailApprover
...
```

And then, using a while loop, iterate over that temp table and grab the values you require to execute the SP, matching by row number.

```
DECLARE @i int = 0
DECLARE @count int = -- length of query results

WHILE (@i < @count)
BEGIN
    SELECT @emailAddress = EmailApprover, ...
    FROM @YourTempResults
    WHERE RowNumber = (@i + 1) -- row number is 1-based

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = @emailAddress, ...

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

We're not doing any heavy lifting here though, so I wouldn't necessarily advice against a cursor in this case. Except that it's been so long, I'd have to refresh on how to code one.  :)

Comment: The another option to do is Create a table with all the information from your query and based on simple Case statement you can execute the sent email proc.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function that did the send mail with the parameters you desire.  Then do a select on your query where the select calls the function.

```
Select SendPMMail(ProjectCode, EmailAddress, ProjectCount) from
(SELECT ProjectCodes.ProjectCode as ProjectCode, 
        COUNT(Projects.ProjectsID) as ProjectCount, 
        ProjectApprovers.EmailApprover as EmailAddress
   FROM Projects 
  INNER JOIN ProjectCodes
        ON Projects.ProjectCodesID=ProjectCodes.ProjectCodesID
  INNER JOIN ProjectApprovers
        ON Projects.ProjectCodesID=ProjectApprovers.ProjectCodesID
  WHERE ProjectApprovers.IsPrimaryApprover=1
  GROUP BY ProjectCodes.ProjectCode, ProjectApprovers.EmailApprover)
```

Comment: You could also do it all in one query but I prefer this way since I find it more readable... i am sure others disagree.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Create a `SQL AGENT JOB` : That will call your stored procedure every 2 time a week ( depending on your need)

- You can see this option on SSMS all the bottom of the SQL Server and configure the settings

You can control what to sent them or whom to send via stored proc.

Comment: His question is regarding how to execute an SP per each row in a result set, not how to schedule such a job.